# Woocommerce checkout field required only if visible

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, required

I'm trying to make the 'business' field in woocommerce checkout required, but only IF the field is actually showing.

I created a radio button field with woocommerce_form_field that displays two options. using javascript I toggle the visibility of the 'business' input field when the radio buttons are checked:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('input[type=radio][name=customer_type]').on('change', function () {
    $('.checkout-bedrijfsnaam').slideToggle();
}); });
```

default css for the 'business' input is:

```
.checkout-bedrijfsnaam { display:none; }
```

Also i made the 'business' field required using the Woocommerce filters 'woocommerce_billing_fields' and 'woocommerce_shipping_fields':

```
$address_fields['billing_company']['required'] = true;
```

that's all going great, however: When the 'business' field is toggled off and is not showing, I get a 'field is required' warning and cannot submit the form. Would it be possible to make the field required, but only when it's actually showing?

I know it has to be, since the fields on the shipping_fields behave in the same manner (not required when checkbox is not checked) but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: then try creating that filed conditionally , that will make your job done, or if it has any filter , try to use that to make it required conditionally .

Comment: the field is created serverside, the condition is client side (which radio button is choosen) so that's not an option i suppose

Comment: for now i'm using the 'woocommerce_checkout_process' action, to do serverside validation and call wc_add_notice when validation fails. but the downside to this is the UI is inconsistent (no star / red border to indicate that the field is required)

Answer (score 1):

If the check is only client-side then instead of hiding it with `display: none;` you might want to remove it from the DOM. When you need it you append it again. You already have the toggle for it so.